# Powering 4V, 2A GSM/GPRS module

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, gsm

I am currently working on a project that involves powering a Quectel GPRS/GSM module, which requires a current of 2A at a voltage of 4V. I intend to power the module using a 5V adapter and a lithium battery.

Considering the module's power requirements and the need for efficient power management, I am uncertain whether to choose a low-dropout regulator (LDO) or a switching regulator for this application. I would like to know which option would be the best fit for my needs.

While researching for an LDO with the appropriate current and voltage ratings on LCSC, I found that the prices were relatively high. I am looking for a more cost-effective alternative that can still provide reliable power to the module.

Could anyone provide insights or recommendations on whether using an LDO or a switching regulator would be more suitable for powering the Quectel GPRS/GSM module in terms of efficiency, cost, and reliability? Additionally, if there are any alternative solutions that can provide similar performance at a lower price point,would greatly help.

Comment: how prec8ise is the 4V requirement?

Comment: Supply voltage range is 3.45-4.25V, recommended is 4V

Comment: with those numbers it sounds like it would be fine to connect it directly to a lithium cell.